# How to look for a specific amount of digits within texbox textChanged event in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, textchanged

In my Windows Form Application, I want to implement a feature where the user has to fill in the serial number of a product that is when matched with any product in the database, the product must appear in a grid. I want to do so using textbox textChanged event.

I am confused in figuring out that either I must prevent firing the textChanged event before the textbox value matches any value in the database. Is there any way to make the textbox expect a specific amount of text or number (my serial numbers are going to be fixed length - like 10001, 10002, 10003) before running the remaining code for showing product in the grid?

Comment: You can check `textbox.TextLength`.

Comment: And combine it with `textBox.MaxLenght`. It will also protect against users pasting more characters then you expect.

Comment: use check textBox1.Text.Length < 5 inside the textchanged event method

Comment: It is not better approach to query to db inside the textChanged because it is requesting everytime when change the text inside the textbox to db.So you should add button and perform such strategy inside the onclick function.So it made call to db when button is clicked and everything is done over the textbox.

Comment: @ArslanAli Exactly I am wondering about it. I want to include such a feature where the textChange event must wait until the min-max numbers are entered. Is it possible to do so with textChanged event?

Comment: Having the criteria `if (textBox1.TextLength < 5) return;` prevents querying database by each change.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: you are most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TextLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.textlength.aspx) property of the `TextBox` to get length of text. For example:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.TextLength < 5)
        return;

    //Send query to database
}
```

**Note:** As it's also mentioned by Jimi in the comments, it's good idea to set `MaxLength` of `TextBox` to prevent entering more text.

Comment: I want to make the textbox wait for the fixed number of input. Once that minimum or maximum numbers are entered, the remaining code must execute to show the product in the grid. Is it possible within textChanged event not with a button?

Comment: The post is directly answering your question. It's checking if the length of text is less than 5 characters, it does nothing, otherwise sends the query to database.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the use of a [MaskedTextBox][1]. A `MaskedTextBox` is similar to a standard `TextBox`, except you define the format of the input text. This can be anything, letters, numbers, dashes, etc.

In your case you accept only input of five digits.

Use the windows forms designer to add a MaskedTextBox, or add one yourself:

```
this.maskedTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
this.maskedTextBox1.Location = ...
this.maskedTextBox1.Size = ...
// etc. Advise: let forms designer do this

// accept only input of five digits:
this.Mask = "00000";
```

The operator sees an indication of the length of the requested input. It is impossible for the operator to type a non-digit. Event when all five digits are entered, but also while typing (`TextChanged`), so if desired you can implement autocompletion. You can even get notified if operator presses one invalid key, so you can inform the operator about the error

Comment: Using `MaskedTextBox` or `NumericUpDown` is a good suggestion as well, but the main point of the question is in running the query in `TextChanged`, when there is 5 characters in the control.